# In Azure, how would I create a Policy that would disable public network access except for a handful of IP ranges?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Here's the policy I have so far:

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts"
        },
        {
          "notEquals": "Deny",
          "field": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/networkAcls.defaultAction"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/25fbc0a9-bd7c-42a3-aa1a-3b75d497ee68",
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/a001fd3d-188f-4b5d-821b-7da978bf7442"
        ],
        "conflictEffect": "audit",
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/networkAcls.ipRules[*]",
            "value": {
              "value": "127.0.0.1",
              "action": "allow"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/networkAcls.ipRules[*]` field allows only 1 value. I'd like to add several more though. I've tried making the `value` field into an array but Azure won't allow me to do that.

I've also found that `Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/networkAcls.ipRules` is not allowed in the `then` clause.

I've had a hard time finding documentation on this. Any ideas?''

*edit* - I can create a policy that ensures any *new* OpenAI resource has a list of allowed IP ranges but cannot modify old ones the same way